# WPF Couldn't load fonts from resources

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, font-family

I want to load my fonts from `Resources` folder and i wrote this code for that.

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0"  FontFamily="/Resources/#IRRoya" FontSize="14" Text="پایگاه داده های موجود : "/>
```

in design everything is OK, but when i run the project, this code doesn't work. 
i also forced my program to run with administrator privilege level, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the BuildAction for the font set to Resource? Also, try specifying the font by full qualification: `MyAssembly;component/Resources/#IRRoya`

Comment: Thanks, it worked !!!